# ValueError: Could not get version for Chrome with this command: google-chrome --version || google-chrome-stable --version

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory

**Hi Everyone**

I'm facing this issue when I'm trying to use **webdriver_manager.Chrome**

> ValueError: Could not get version for Chrome with this command: google-chrome --version || google-chrome-stable --version

This happens when I try:

> driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

I'm writing a script to run in Google Colab and I need to make this easy to run, because my intention is share this script with people that doesn't know programming.

This code works normally at VsCode, **I get this trouble only in Google Colab.**

Thanks!

Comment: did you solved the problem?